# Wifi won't show up [Solved]

Tags: wifi

So I decided to screw around with operating systems I I downloaded this. I'm a complete noob so my question is:
I can't turn the wifi on.
I googled this about 20 times and none worked.
So, can someone help me?

Edit : it was the switch. I had to press fn + f12

Comment: Edit : it was the switch. I had to press fn + f12

Comment: Its better if you post an answer and choose it as answered. This ways it's easier to recognized at solved.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a screenshot with what you see?
Normally you have in the upper right an icon for WiFi, clicking that one gives you the option to turn on/off the WiFi.

It's also possible to go to system settings -> network